# Replace values in HTML thats inside <script> tags with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, replace

I've spend most of my weekend being blind on what seems like a simple fix, so therefor i'm turning to you guys expertise.

I have X instances of the following script tag (but always with the same class name):

```
   <script type="text-html" class="tmpl-popup"><div class="acf-fc-popup">
        <ul>
                                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-layout="one_column" data-min="" data-max=""><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-image="%%THEMEPATH%%/images/admin/layouts/one_column.png" /> <span>One Column</span></a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-layout="two_columns" data-min="" data-max=""><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-image="%%THEMEPATH%%/images/admin/layouts/two_columns.png" /> <span>Two Columns</span></a>
                </li>
                        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="focus"></a>
    </div>
</script>
```

In which I first need to replace the %%THEMEPATH%% with a variable that contains a site name which could be "http://mydomainname.com". When that replace is done I need the src of the img tags inside the script tags are replaced with the value data-image value.

But I can't seem to get it to work the way I want because the HTML is inside a script tag. Here is the what i've been working on so far, but it' doesn't really seem to do the job :(

```
jQuery(".tmpl-popup").each(function(index){

        var haystack = jQuery(this).html(),
            needle = haystack.replace(/%%THEMEPATH%%/g, themePath);

            jQuery(this).html(needle);

            var popup = jQuery(jQuery.parseHTML(haystack)),
                imageSrc = jQuery(popup).find('img').data('image'),

            jQuery(popup).find('img').attr('src',imageSrc);

            jQuery(this).html(popup);       

    });
```

So thanks in advance if anyone can help me out there :(

Comment: `var popup` is parsing the unchanged string `haystack` not `needle`

Comment: @charlietfl is right, this is the fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/g864nmxg/. You should put it as an answer :)

Comment: @Baro - This is close to working but as you can see in the last result! It uses the one_column.png src instead of the src from the data which is two_column.png :/

Comment: True... change these 2 lines `var imageSrc = jQuery(popup).find('img').data('image'); jQuery(popup).find('img').attr('src',imageSrc);` with this: `jQuery(popup).find('img').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('image'));
 });`. The fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g864nmxg/1/

Comment: This seemed to solve the problem until vendor will fix their PHP lib so that it allows me to change it serverside instead. How do I set your comment as answer?

Comment: Just found out the script you made which works in all browsers but gives me the following error in Mozilla Firefox: "TypeError: a.offset(...) is undefined" and when I check your fiddle:  jsfiddle.net/g864nmxg in Firefox it's last result is not showing up :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function callback version of jQuery's `html` and use a global string replace for the `%%THEMEPATH%%` part, and then (as you came up with) parse the HTML and handle the images in it before going back to source to update the `script` element text:

```
$("script.tmpl-popup").html(function(_, html) {
  // Update %%THEMEPATH%%
  html = html.replace(/%%THEMEPATH%%/g, "http://example.com");

  // Update src: `$.parseHTML` gives us an array of the top-level elements.
  // we loop through them, finding any `img[data-image]` that they contain,
  // and updating the `src` on those.
  return $.parseHTML(html).map(function(element) {
    // Note: If it were possible for an `img[data-image]` to be *at* the top
    // level, you'd need: `$(element).find("img[data-image]").addBack("img[data-image").attr...
    $(element).find("img[data-image]").attr("src", function() {
      return this.getAttribute("data-image"); // or $(this).attr("data-image") if you want more jQuery :-)
    });
    return element.outerHTML;
  });
});
```

```js
$("script.tmpl-popup").html(function(_, html) {
  // Update %%THEMEPATH%%
  html = html.replace(/%%THEMEPATH%%/g, "http://example.com");
  
  // Update src: `$.parseHTML` gives us an array of the top-level elements.
  // we loop through them, finding any `img[data-image]` that they contain,
  // and updating the `src` on those.
  return $.parseHTML(html).map(function(element) {
    // Note: If it were possible for an `img[data-image]` to be *at* the top
    // level, you'd need: `$(element).find("img[data-image]").addBack("img[data-image").attr...
    $(element).find("img[data-image]").attr("src", function() {
      return this.getAttribute("data-image"); // or $(this).attr("data-image") if you want more jQuery :-)
    });
    return element.outerHTML;
  });
});
```

```html
<p>You'll have to use right-click Inspect Element to see that the change has happened. :-)</p>
<script type="text-html" class="tmpl-popup"><div class="acf-fc-popup">
        <ul>
                                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-layout="one_column" data-min="" data-max=""><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-image="%%THEMEPATH%%/images/admin/layouts/one_column.png" /> <span>One Column</span></a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-layout="two_columns" data-min="" data-max=""><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-image="%%THEMEPATH%%/images/admin/layouts/two_columns.png" /> <span>Two Columns</span></a>
                </li>
                        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="focus"></a>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text-html" class="tmpl-popup"><div class="acf-fc-popup">
        <ul>
                                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-layout="one_column" data-min="" data-max=""><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-image="%%THEMEPATH%%/images/admin/layouts/one_column.png" /> <span>One Column</span></a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-layout="two_columns" data-min="" data-max=""><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-image="%%THEMEPATH%%/images/admin/layouts/two_columns.png" /> <span>Two Columns</span></a>
                </li>
                        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="focus"></a>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text-html" class="tmpl-popup"><div class="acf-fc-popup">
        <ul>
                                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-layout="one_column" data-min="" data-max=""><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-image="%%THEMEPATH%%/images/admin/layouts/one_column.png" /> <span>One Column</span></a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-layout="two_columns" data-min="" data-max=""><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-image="%%THEMEPATH%%/images/admin/layouts/two_columns.png" /> <span>Two Columns</span></a>
                </li>
                        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="focus"></a>
    </div>
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So all of that would have to be wrapped in a ,each or in document ready is enough?

Comment: @Johns3n: You don't need either, if your `script` tag containing this is at the bottom of `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag (or really, just anywhere after the `script` tags you want it to operate on). `ready` is *seriously* over-used. Put scripts at the bottom, which is best for perceived page load time anyway, and you don't need it.

Comment: Ofc <scripts> at bottom if possible :) But was looking for the init. which is just when the browser hits it?

Comment: @Johns3n: The code above will run when encountered, yes.